# loading images outside htdocs delay

Tags: php, image

I have a image gallery system where I store images outside of the `htdocs` folder. Now as soon as the number of images exceeds around 150 images, the site has issues loading the images. I get a lot of failed image loading icons, a template that can't cope with the missing images and so on.

When I store the images inside the `htdocs` folder and don't use my img controller their is no issue what so ever. I tried different ways of preloading but in essence they do not work as I am loading images with php.

Img class + method

```php
class Img extends MY_Controller 
{
    /**
     * Stuur een image locatie door buiten de root
     * @param $file de naam van de foto
     * @param $foldername de naam van de folder
     * @return het path en correcte header
     */
    public function jpg($foldername, $file)
    {
        if(($foldername != null) && ($file != null))
        {
            $filename = basename($file);
            $file_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            switch($file_extension) 
            {
                case "gif": $contentType="image/gif"; break;
                case "png": $contentType="image/png"; break;
                case "jpeg": $contentType="image/jpeg"; break;
                case "jpg": $contentType="image/jpeg"; break;
                default:
            }

            $path = DOCROOT . GALLERYS . $foldername . '/' . $file;
            header('Content-type: ' . $contentType);
            readfile($path);
        }      
    }
}
```

The foreach loop inside the html page

```php
foreach ($images as $img) : 
  $imageLocation = 'img/jpg/' . $folderName . '/' . $img['image_name']; 
  $id = $selected_gallery . $counter;
?>
```

Some html use

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <a href="#<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url($imageLocation); ?>" alt="<?php echo $selected_gallery . ' ' . $counter; ?>">
  </a>
</div>
```

I would like to know if their is a way to fix the loading issues, maybe with a callback to know for sure the image is loaded before going threw with the next cycle of the foreach loop. I have some experience with php but I am still a novice so if at all possible explain why it is happening if you provide a solution. I like to understand before I fix.

Comment: How big are the images? Is it possible that your script is timing out before all of the images have been read and sent?

Comment: I doubt it, the sizes range from 170kb to a max of 300kb.

Comment: And I use the scrip image by image.